# Marketing Cloud - retrieving Federation Id (SSO)

Tags: marketing-cloud

We want to retrieve SSO Federation Id of user using API object "SsoIdentity".
Could you please confirm is it possible as i cannot find Attribute for Account User  Id in properties of API object "SsoIdentity".
We want to do it using WSProxy.
Is it possible?  how to apply filer to retrieve specific account user id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the **SsoIdentity** object is retrievable. The information you are looking for should be available on the [AccountUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/accountuser.htm) object.

Here's an example call to retrieve AccountUser with an applied filter:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1")

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols = ["AccountUserID", "ActiveFlag", "ChallengeAnswer", "ChallengePhrase", "CreatedDate",  "CustomerKey", "Email",  "ID",  "IsAPIUser",  "IsLocked", "LastSuccessfulLogin",  "ModifiedDate",  "MustChangePassword",  "Name",  "NotificationEmailAddress",  "Password",  "Roles", "UserID",  "UserPermissions"];
var filter = {Property: "AccountUserID", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: "100xxxxxx"};

try{
  var data = prox.retrieve("AccountUser", cols, filter);
      Write(Stringify(data));
    }catch(e){
  Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
```

You will need to dig in to retrieve the `FederationObject` and `SsoIdentities`, but above should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the code, However, how to retrieve array attributes like "Roles" or "UserPermissions" using SSJS , Can you please send sample snippet for it?

Comment: I'm not on my laptop at the moment but will look into this later

Comment: Here's a good write-up on account auditing: https://charliefay.medium.com/sfmc-account-user-audit-check-roles-and-permissions-via-api-c14356be0114