# Using Marketing Cloud SOAP API - is it possible to retrieve the Federated ID for the AccountUser?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I have been able to retrieve the AccountUser information and based on the documentation I should be able to get the SsoIndentity for the user. Unfortunately it gives me an error saying it isn't a field on the AccountUser object. Is there a way to get it or am I looking at the wrong object.

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
           <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
           <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts> // to enable child accounts
           <Properties>email</Properties>
           <Properties>ActiveFlag</Properties>
           <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
           <Properties>isAPIUser</Properties>
           <Properties>UserID</Properties>
           <Properties>ID</Properties>
           <Properties>LastSuccessfulLogin</Properties>
           <Properties>SsoIdentities</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
Error: The Request Property(s) SsoIdentities do not match with the fields of AccountUser retrieve
```

Any information would be great thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Marketing Cloud - retrieving Federation Id (SSO)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289128/marketing-cloud-retrieving-federation-id-sso)

Comment: Unfortunately I have seen that. I haven't been able to figure out what they meant by digging through the AccountUser as there doesn't seem to be any information about SSO or Federated ID in the return from their code.

Comment: I see, yes, you are right and it was also unsuccessful for me to retrieve it so far via `AccountUser` and some filters. And the `SSOIdentity` object is indeed not retrievable. Will check it later if others in the meanwhile will not suggest a clue.

Comment: it is not possible to get this from the API, currently, the only way to see this value is within the UI. You can however set this value with the API